# how to remove gimp and darktable apps?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, gimp

I'm a Ubuntu 20.04 user, not experienced linux user.
Problem is following:
I have two gimp installations. First one I managed to remove with package-management. The second not.I want to get rid of ALL gimp staff.
Same thing with the darktable. It says removing not avalable.
the sourse for darktable is: ubuntu-jammy-universe (deb)

When I try: sudo apt-get update it gives me a promt:
E: Tyyppi "gpg" is unknown on row 1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics:darktable.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Comment: How did you install the other? Flatpak? AppImage? For flatpak, `flatpak uninstall org.gimp.GIMP (I think). If you remove Gimp, you also have to remove the [user profile](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/GIMPProfile/).

Comment: Both are installed from Ubuntu software center.

Comment: Thanks xenoid. If I try to install or uninstall something I get the always the same answer:  E:Type "gpg" is not known on line 1 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list.d/  and E:list of sources could not be read. I'm not a expert on Ubuntu or any other computer staff!

Comment: Maybe you should add the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the list of files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Btw, 20.04 is out of service since May 1st...

Comment: Xenoid, I'm not able to install anything. Nor can I read lists of files you suggested. The prompt is always the same :   E:Type "gpg" is not known on line 1 in source list/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and E:list of sources could not be read. So I can't install version 22 of ubuntu either.

Comment: So I suggest you ask a very different question: "How to repair a broken APT sources list". As it is this question only appeals to the few that use photo/image apps, not to the APT exprts.  And maybe post a screenshot of the message because there may be some missing/extra spaces that could be significant and could be missed out with just a copy/pasted text.

Comment: I've given wrong info, actually I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS + Gnome 42.5.  Thank you Xenoid for being patient with me. I've bought my PC Ubuntu ready installed, and the system language is finnish. So pasting the screenshot is no good for most of the readers. /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Lupa evätty (= permission denied)

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d: On hakemisto (= it is a directory)